# What would cause a web service method to change the value of a variable passed in?

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to web service development, so maybe I'm not aware of something... I have a web service class currently has two methods in it.  The below is just the first part of the second method.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getPassengerName")
public String getPassengerName(@WebParam(name = "passengerId ") int passengerId)
{
   //MySQL elements
   Connection connection;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   String returnValue = "start method with passengerId having a value of: " + passengerId;
```

and when I run a "test web service" in NetBeans, passing in a 1, the passengerId appended to the string is 0.

```
getPassengerName Method invocation

Method parameter(s)

Type    Value
int     1
Method returned

java.lang.String : "start method with passengerId having a value of: 0"
```

What would make this happen? I appreciate any insight anyone can offer.

**New Content**

In response to EJK's post about the value not being in passengerID, I have added more of the screen print from the "Test Web Service" test.

```
SOAP Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getPassengerName xmlns:ns2="http://database_access.lytthouseair.com/">
            <passengerId>1</passengerId>
        </ns2:getPassengerName>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sounds like default value (0 for integer) is being applied.  My hypothesis is that "passengerId" is not present in the request.

Comment: I am not familiar with this approach of calling web services however the output you show indicates that an integer parameter is set to 1, but I do not see anything indicating the 1 was applied to the named parameter "passengerId"

Comment: Hi EJK, thank you for such a quick response.  I have added to my post the SOAP Request input; which indicates that the input of 1 is going into the element passengerID

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant or not, but your comment indicates "passengerID" and your code indicates "passengerId".  Note that the last character differs by case.

Comment: Yes sorry, that's just a typo in the comment.  Not relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have hit upon the issue.  I think it is a bug in the NetBeans IDE.  I created a new method, which I modeled after this one that doesn't work:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getPassengerName")
public String getPassengerName(@WebParam(name = "passengerId ") int passengerId)
```

And typed in this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getFirstName")
public String getFirstName(@WebParam(name="passengerNumber") int passengerNumber)
```

Then I simply copied all of my code into this new method, and when I checked the value of the variable passed in right at the top of the code, it worked - 1 was still 1 (not 0).

This was in NetBeans 8.0